# Holomorphic function $f\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{2n-1} \right)=\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Does there exists a holomorphic function $f:B_2(0)\to\mathbb C$ such that $$f\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{n},\;\forall n\in\mathbb Z^+.$$

I do not have an idea?

Comment: Think about the zero set of the function $f(z)-z/2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  I think you mean $f(z)-2z$, no?

Comment: @lulu Yes, thanks.

Comment: so, $0=f(z)-2z=f(z_n)-2z_n (n\to\infty)=f(\frac{1}{2n})-\frac{1}{n} (n\to\infty)= f(\frac{1}{2n-1})-\frac{2}{2n-1} (n\to\infty)=f(0)-0=0$

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299279

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$ z_n = \frac{1}{2n}, \qquad w_n = \frac{1}{2n - 1} $$
then
$$ f(z_n) = 2z_n, \qquad f(w_n) = \frac{2}{(2n - 1) + 1} = \frac{2}{1/w_n + 1} = \frac{2w_n}{1 + w_n} $$
By the identity theorem we get the contradiction on the unit disc
$$ 2z = f(z) = \frac{2z}{1 + z} $$